# excel formula to import values from one sheet to another with criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have two sheets(Sheet1,Sheet2)
Both sheets have two common columns named ID and name.
Sheet1 have values of ID and name but Sheet2 is empty.
I can't copy past the whole column cause both sheets are in different order of ID.
So I want a formula in Sheet 2 that will have ID as argument and return the name value for that ID from sheet1
[Sheet1 with ID and Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32b3S.png)
[Sheet2, where I'll give ID and the formula will return Corresponding name from sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKIKS.png)

Comment: Assuming ids are unique you can use a VLOOKUP

Answer (score 2):

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can u explain the arguments here?
It's searching A2 on column A in Sheet1 and then?

Comment: You could find the details in the [help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)